# Max Last Updated Time from 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Details columns in 3 table getting updated constantly 
I would like to pick up latest lastUpdateTime 
between given datetime 
where IDs match from 3 table

```
tblClient
ID,     AddressDetail, lastUpdateTime
789     Address     '2013-09-27 00:00:00:000'
789     Address     '2013-09-23 00:00:00:000'
897     Address     '2013-09-22 00:00:00:000'
354     Address     '2013-09-28 00:00:00:000'

tblOrder
ID,     OrdersDetail, lastUpdateTime
789     Order       '2013-09-26 00:00:00:000'
897     Order       '2013-09-30 00:00:00:000'
897     Order       '2013-09-27 00:00:00:000'
354     Order       '2013-09-30 00:00:00:000'

tblAccount
ID,     AccountDetail, lastUpdateTime
789     Detail      '2013-09-23 00:00:00:000'
897     Detail      '2013-09-25 00:00:00:000'
354     Detail      '2013-09-28 00:00:00:000'
```

--this wont do it

```
SELECT a.ID,a.AccountDetail,max(A.lastUpdateTime)   
From tblClient A
left join tblOrder B
on A.ID = B.ID
left join tblAccount C
on C.ID = A.ID 
where A.LastUpdateTime between '2013-09-20 00:00:00:000' and '2013-09-30 00:00:00:000'
```

Comment: Where is the `pin` column defined?

Comment: What database are you using? How do you intend to deal with ties?

Comment: sql server, there will be duplicate. columns that are updated in 3 tables. whatever is updated i would like to show

Comment: Ok so if two records tied for the latest you'd want to show both? Or perhaps do you want to show the latest from each table? Perhaps if you showed expected output it would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `UNION` rather than a `JOIN`, order the result then take the first row for each ID:

```
SELECT ID, detail, LastUpdateTime
FROM (
 SELECT ID, detail, LastUpdateTime,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY LastUpdateTime desc) rownum
 FROM (
  SELECT ID, AddressDetail as detail, lastUpdateTime
  From tblClient
  WHERE LastUpdateTime between '2013-09-20 00:00:00:000' and '2013-09-30 00:00:00:000'
 UNION
  SELECT ID, orderDetail, lastUpdateTime
  From tblOrder
  WHERE LastUpdateTime between '2013-09-20 00:00:00:000' and '2013-09-30 00:00:00:000'
 UNION
  SELECT ID, AccountDetail, lastUpdateTime
  From tblAccount
  WHERE LastUpdateTime between '2013-09-20 00:00:00:000' and '2013-09-30 00:00:00:000'
 ) x
) y
WHERE rownum = 1
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a5453/1)

This also has the advantage that the detail column of latest the row is also returned.

Comment: It's TOP 1 since it's [SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971229/max-last-updated-time-from-3-tables#comment28021308_18971229)

Comment: thats just select one row

Comment: I need a table something like this

Comment: -- need to pic from tblClient
789     Address     '2013-09-27 00:00:00:000'
897     Address     '2013-09-22 00:00:00:000'
354     Address     '2013-09-28 00:00:00:000'

-- need to pic from tblOrder
ID,     OrdersDetail, lastUpdateTime
789     Order       '2013-09-26 00:00:00:000'
897     Order       '2013-09-30 00:00:00:000'
354     Order       '2013-09-30 00:00:00:000'

-- need to pic from tblAccount
ID,     AccountDetail, lastUpdateTime
789     Detail      '2013-09-23 00:00:00:000'
897     Detail      '2013-09-25 00:00:00:000'

Comment: Do you need the latest for every ID in the time slot?

Comment: OK - query changed to return the latest row for every ID that has data in the time slot

Comment: aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
Column 'tblClient.ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Invalid column name 'LastUpdateTime'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Invalid column name 'ID'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Invalid column name 'LastUpdateTime'.  Thanks Bohemian...I figure out something with Union..

Comment: I left a max() in there accidentally from an earlier attempt. Fixed now, and see SQLFiddle link for live demo

Comment: As you see on fiddle tables..query picks up one record from each table..

Would like to pick all records that are matches between dates

from tblclient 789, first record cause thats is the latest one,897,and 354
from tblOrder 789,897 first record cause thats is the latest one ,and 354
from tblAccount all of them.. cause all these records got updated.
they are latest updated records.

Comment: It should be more like Latest records from 3 tables or something instead of Max